# Leveling a 2x8 sill plate on top of a cmu wall

Tags: sill

What type of shim do I use to shim up a sill plate 1/4 inch on top of a cmu block wall?

Comment: Are the blocks that out of level? What's the actual problem? My first response is a treated wood shim of your own making, but I'm curious if there's more to the story.

Comment: Pour a bond beam and make the top of **that** level? I kinda like that option, just because it will make the whole thing more secure than the average CMU foundation. Call the mason back to fix the wall?

Comment: I don't know your exact problem, but typically you don't shim a sill plate. Shim the floor truss/joist if you're shimming anything. Cut a shim out of wood.

Comment: Since concrete contractors do not have that much luck on getting concrete level I have used non-shrink grout under sill plates to get them level, but that's the whole perimeter.... Set with a transit....